# How can I set the values of select lists if one of them is the Parent LOV of the other?

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, selectlist

I have two select list : A and B.

A is the parent LOV of B. So when A changes B gets refreshed and changes based on the value of A.
--> B now has lower values to chose from.

Now my problem is that when I select values via PL SQL into the select list (from the database) that select list B never returns the wanted value but the values I would get when I choose the value from A.

--> B should be set to John and A should be set to IT.
--> B returns null value but I can choose all people that work in IT.

When I remove A as Parent LOV then the right value is inserted into B but the list dosent adapt to A.

I use Oracle APEX v.19.1.0.00.15

Comment: To clarify, your problem is that you have two Select lists, one being the Parent of the other. And when you try to set their value through PLSQL(I am assuming this is a Dynamic action with the action block being PLSQL), the parent gets set, but the child isnt.  Is my understanding here correct?

Comment: Yes ! The parent gets set and because of it the second List gets refreshed and loses the value it orginally got from the PL SQL insert. I couldnt find a work around and im overall at the end with my newbie knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried it out myself.

I had a button that triggers a Dynamic action. The action was PLSQL code and it just assigned the parent and child. If I set it to assign both of them in the same action, it didnt work, if I separated them out it did.

So change out the actions in your DA(dynamic action) first you have a PLSQL action that assigns the parent item, and you also need to set the Items to return to return this item. Then you have a second action that is the same thing, just for the child.

This works for me, so I am hoping it works for you, let me know if it is still causing you issues